# "Error Implementing AudioServiceActivity in Flutter: Unresolved Package 'ryanheise'"

Tags: flutter, android-manifest, audio-service

I'm trying to implement audio_services in my app to read podcast while device is locked,

When I try to change this :

```
 <!-- EDIT THE android:name ATTRIBUTE IN YOUR EXISTING "ACTIVITY" ELEMENT -->
    <activity android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity" ...>
```

I get this error :

```
Class referenced in the manifest, com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity, was not found in the project or the libraries
Unresolved package 'ryanheise'
```

I've tried numerous solutions, but nothing seems to fix this issue. Here is the relevant portion of my pubspec.yaml:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.6 <3.0.0'
...
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  record: ^4.4.4
  audio_service: ^0.18.10
  ffmpeg_kit_flutter: ^5.1.0
```

I Tried

```
flutter clean and flutter build
flutter flutter pub cache repair
...
```

restarting Android Studio
...

What could be causing this error, and how can I fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm running into the same issue